# help with routing edge flow

Tags: modeling, workflow

I have shading issues can anybody help me with this problem...its half sphere and some square object i make union with bool tool:

[image]

Comment: Hello, maybe show a picture of the object you're trying to achieve?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NqMOL.jpg look here

Comment: thanks, maybe share your file here: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=wBoMdq3R" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/wBoMdq3R/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This kind of topology works but it needs a bit more edge loops for your sphere than what you currently have:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: did u use bevel and after that make changes or make all cuts by knife

Comment: yes use bevel then make some changes (join vertices with J or cut withe knife)